# Cohen's Kappa and Kappa Statistic in WEKA

Tags: math, machine-learning, statistics, weka

I was wondering if the Kappa Statistic metric provided by WEKA is an inter-annotator agreement metric.

Is is similar to Cohen's Kappa or Fleiss Kappa?

Comment: I would ask this on the [Weka mailing list](https://list.waikato.ac.nz/mailman/listinfo/wekalist) where you will probably get an answer from the Weka developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This slide is from the chapter 5 slides for Witten, et al.'s textbook.[image]

https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/book.html 
(Because I have modified many of the slides, the slide number will be different.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it in my research. It is Cohen's Kappa.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).